# How to connect postgres to ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible

**Objective:**

My objective is to connect postgres 9.3 using Ansible 2.8.3, and perform postgres operations using ansible.

I have created a yaml file to install postgres, this file also creates a database using the yaml script.

I tried resolving this error by changing the contents of the `sudoer` file, but it damaged the file forcing me to reinstall ubuntu and ansible.

**Ansible Code:**

---

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: ensure apt cache is up to date
    apt: update_cache=yes
  - name: ensure packages are installed
    apt: name={{item}}
    with_items:
    - postgresql
    - libpq-dev
    - python-psycopg2

- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: emgda
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    dbname: myapp
    dbuser: emgda
    dbpassword: Entrib!23

  tasks:
  - name: ensure database is created
    postgresql_db: name={{dbname}}

  - name: ensure user has access to database
    postgresql_user: db={{dbname}} name={{dbuser}} password={{dbpassword}} priv=ALL

  - name: ensure user does not have unnecessary privilege
    postgresql_user: name={{dbuser}} role_attr_flags=NOSUPERUSER,NOCREATEDB

  - name: ensure no other user can access the database
    postgresql_privs: db={{dbname}} role=PUBLIC type=database priv=ALL state=absent
```

...

After running this file I have come across below **error**:

`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}`

> NOTE: Can anyone kindly help me resolve this issue. I am new to Ansible. I am following [this link](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/postgresql.yml) to practice already running Ansible script.

Answer (score 1):

[Escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation) works fine in the first play

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
```

The default *become_user* is `root`. This means that the user who is running the playbook (see [ansible_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters)) is able to escalate privilege *`sudo su -`*.

The second play escalates to user `emgda`. This means that the user who is running the playbook shall escalate privilege *`sudo su emgda`*

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: emgda
```

This requires a password which is missing, resulting in the error

```
sudo: a password is required
```

The solutions are

1) Provide the password in the command-line with [--ask-become-pass](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#command-line-options), or

2) Provide the password in the variable [ansible_become_password](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#connection-variables), or

3) configure sudoers to escalate the privilege without password

```
<user-running-playbook> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set `become: yes` in your playbook so ansible trying to switch to the root user. According to the error message - `sudo: a password is required`, you didn't set the `--ask-become-pass` option during the playbook run and didn't set passwordless sudo for your ansible user.

So you need to run your playbook with `--ask-become-pass` option, or setup ability to use sudo without password for user that you user for Ansible.